# Lag on Controlling an ACPI Device

Tags: c#, driver, wmi, hardware, acpi

I am working in a laptop reseller company and they are making a control center for their laptops. The keyboards they are using use ACPI methods to change their RGB colors.
I have decompiled the previous control center and exported 2 functions to use.

First one is

```
private void WriteACPI(uint ioctrl, int addr, int data)
{
    IntPtr intPtr = CreateFile("\\\\.\\ACPIDriver", [hidden], 3u, IntPtr.Zero, 3u, 0u, IntPtr.Zero);

    if (intPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        int[] source = new int[2] { addr, data };
        IntPtr intPtr2 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(8);
        Marshal.Copy(source, 0, intPtr2, 2);
        int outBuffer = 0;
        DeviceIoControl(intPtr, ioctrl, intPtr2, 8, ref outBuffer, 4, out var _, IntPtr.Zero);
        //Console.WriteLine("out buffer: " + outBuffer);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(intPtr2);
        CloseHandle(intPtr);
    }
}
```

But since there is an (**I think**) interval in the driver, It gets the commands (changes the keyboard's colors) every approximately 0.7 seconds.

The second function I exported uses WMI commands.

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        ManagementScope s = new(@"\\.\root\WMI");
        ManagementPath p = new("AcpiTest_MULong.InstanceName='ACPI\\PNP0C14\\1_1'");

        managementObject = new ManagementObject(s, p, null);
        sw.Start();

        Value <<= 16;
        Addr = Value + Addr;

        managementObject.InvokeMethod("GetSetULong", new object[] { Addr });
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("sw in testing : " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

The problem here is that InvokeMethod takes about 180 milliseconds. It is faster than the first method but since I am invoking it for times (for r, g and b values, and for 1 triggering the change value) It gets up to 700 milliseconds again.

I have tried sending 4 ulongs in InvokeMethod object array to make it quick in 180 ms but it just took the first object in that array.

My purpose is to add Gradient change and Music mode etc modes so I should be able to control the keyboard at least 10 times a second (less than 100 ms).

I want to know if there is an alternative method to send ACPI commands to ECRam or a method to make WMI faster. (I have no access to driver's source code, I tried decompiling .sys file with IDAPro and got a C-like file but I couldn't get much information I can use)
Thank you.

Comment: WMI is slow anyway (as there's loads of layers of indirection involved) - can't you do everything through `DeviceIoControl` like in your first example?

Comment: That said, have you attached your profiler to see why WMI is so slow? If not, **why not**?

Comment: Oh, so you're saying that both examples (`DeviceIoControl` _and_ `InvokeMethod`) are slow?

Comment: DeviceIoControl sends the ioctrl but there is like 700 ms lag. For example when I send
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 in 100 ms delays, it just get 1 and 7, not the others.

Comment: Don't you have access to the actual driver source code? If not, then that's a problem... computer OEMs should always be able to service drivers for their own products...

Comment: I don't :( If I had, everything could be easier.

Comment: Complain to your boss then: tell them you can't do what's been asked of you without being able to build the driver yourself - failing that, demand a raise and then [bust out Ghidra](https://ghidra-sre.org/) and see if you can change the poll frequency in the compiled driver binary.

Comment: I will try reducing poll frequency, I haven't thought about that, thank you. If that doesn't work, I mean, is there any other methods I can use?

Comment: I don't think so, no, sorry.

Comment: BTW, you need to correctly dispose of your unmanaged objects in your C# code: add a `try/finally` and use `SafeHandle` in your `WriteACPI` method to ensure that `FreeHGlobal` and `CloseHandle` are always invoked even in event of a runtime exception. Also `ManagementObject` instances need to be wrapped in a `using()` block or statement.

Comment: I really thank you for your help, I will try these.